# prove that $-1 \le \frac{ac+bd}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}} \le 1$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> For the real numbers $a, b, c, d$ prove that $$-1 \le \dfrac{ac+bd}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}} \le 1$$

Actually if we let $\vec{u} = (a, b)$ and $\vec{v} = (c, d)$ then by dot product we got $$\begin{split} cosθ & = \dfrac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|} \\ & =\dfrac{ac+bd}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}} \end{split}$$ 
But $-1 \le cosθ \le 1$ hence $$-1 \le \dfrac{ac+bd}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}} \le 1$$

Is it possible to prove the above inequality using only standard inequalities like AM-GM, Cauchy-Swarz, Rearrangement inequality or Jensen inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

For $2$ sets of numbers $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, we have by above inequality

$$(a^2+b^2)\cdot (c^2+d^2) \geq (ac+bd)^2$$
$$ -\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\cdot (c^2+d^2)} \leq (ac+bd) \leq \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\cdot (c^2+d^2)}$$
$$-1 \leq \frac{(ac+bd)}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\cdot (c^2+d^2)}} \leq 1$$

Comment: yeah but C-S is true for positive reals.$a, b, c, d$ may be negative

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to $$\sqrt{(ac+bd)^2}=|ac+bd|\leqslant\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2},$$ which is an immediate consequence of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ is equivalent to $x^2 \leq 1$.
Use that fact to prove the given inequality, i.e.
just re-work it, raising to the power of 2. And it will be proven.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity,

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)-(ac+bd)^2=(ad-bc)^2\ge0$$